# Blank results while using Tokens Regex rules to identify Named Entities

Tags: macros, stanford-nlp

I am struggling with writing the correct rule which involves macros to identify organizations in a text.

To Identify Matrix Inc. in:

With it's rising share prices Matrix Inc. has come out a winner this quarter.

I am trying to check for words like Inc within the entity and thus defined a macros and rule as below:

```
$ORGANIZATION_TITLES = "/pharmaceuticals?|group|corp|corporation|international|co.?|inc.?|incorporated|holdings|motors|ventures|parters|llc|limited liability corporation|pvt.? ltd.?/"

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 1
 {
  ruleType: "tokens",
  pattern: ([$ORGANIZATION_TITLES]), 
  action:  ( Annotate($0, ner, "ORGANIZATION") )
}

 ENV.defaults["stage"] = 2
 { ( [{tag:NNP}]+? ($ORGANIZATION_TITLES)) => ORGANIZATION }
```

I tried using bindings also and then applying the rule.

```
env.bind("$ORGANIZATION_TITLES", TokenSequencePattern.compile(env,"/pharmaceuticals?|group|corp|corporation|international|co.?|inc.?|incorporated|holdings|motors|ventures|parters|llc|limited liability corporation|pvt.? ltd.?/"));
```

Nothing seems to be working. I need to define more complex pattern rules involving macros like:

```
pattern:  ( [ { ner:PERSON } ]+ /,/*? ($TITLES_CORPORATE_PREFIXES)*? $TITLES_CORPORATE+? /,/*? /of|for/? /,/*? [ { ner:ORGANIZATION } ]+ )
```

where $TITLES_CORPORATE_PREFIXES and $TITLES_CORPORATE are macros similar to $ORGANIZATION_TITLES.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String  rulesFile = "D:\\Workspace\\resource\\NERRulesFile.txt";
        String dataFile = "D:\\Workspace\\resource\\GoldSetSentences.txt";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        // pipeline.addAnnotator(new TokensRegexAnnotator(rulesFile));
        String inputText = "Bill Edelman , CEO and Chairman , for Paragonix commented on the Supply Agreement with Essential Pharmaceuticals .";


        Annotation document = new Annotation(inputText.toLowerCase());
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
        CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv(), rulesFile);
        /* Next we can go over the annotated sentences and extract the annotated words,
         Using the CoreLabel Object */
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
        {

            List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions(sentence);

            for(MatchedExpression phrase : matched){

                // Print out matched text and value
                System.out.println("matched: " + phrase.getText() + " with value " + phrase.getValue());
                // Print out token information
                CoreMap cm = phrase.getAnnotation();
                for (CoreLabel token : cm.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
                {

                    String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
                    String lemma = token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class);
                    String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
                    String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
                    System.out.println("matched token: " + "word="+word + ", lemma="+lemma + ", pos=" + pos + "ne=" + ne);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you setting TokensRegex to be case insensitive? `env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` and `env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)` if called programmatically (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html)

Comment: @GaborAngeli No I am not using the case_insensitive flags. I've edited the question and added my code. Maybe you can glance through it and tell me if I need to set the token to be case insensitive. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rules file that should work:

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

$ORGANIZATION_TITLES = "/inc\.|corp\./"

{ pattern: ([{pos: NNP}]+ $ORGANIZATION_TITLES), action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "RULE_FOUND_ORG") ) }
```

I have made some changes to our code base to make the TokensRegexAnnotator more easily accessible.  You will need to get the latest version from GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex -tokensregex.rules organization.rules -file samples.txt -outputFormat text -tokensregex.caseInsensitive
```

If you run this command or the equivalent Java API call it should work:

Comment: for some reason this is not working for me. It just says "Reading TokensRegex rules from D:\Workspace\resource\NERRulesFile.txt" and then nothing. Also in a multi-token expression like Paragonix Inc. the approach you mention will only mark the Inc. part of it as Organization right? I wanted to use a rule like pattern: ( ( [ { tag: "/NNP.*/"} ]+) ([ { ner:ORGANIZATION_TITLES } ]+) ) to make this work but I haven't been successful.

Comment: Please see edited answer.  You will need to download the latest version of Stanford CoreNLP from GitHub as I have made code changes to make it easier to use TokensRegexAnnotator.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Firstly, while building the project i get a null pointer exception. "Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'stanford-corenlp'.
java.lang.NullPointerException" Secondly, when I add the tokensregex option in the annotators it throws an error saying it could not find this annotation. Lastly, I am not using command line so where do I exercise the option of "-tokensregex.rules organization.rules -file samples.txt -outputFormat text" ? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just to add..I am running this code through eclipse.

Comment: Could you fix the errors in the project so that I can build the github version at my end without errors. I got null pointer exceptions while building the code base.

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting, it builds fine for me.

Comment: Here is a link for specifying program arguments in Eclipse: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/cmd.pdf

Comment: Here is some general info on using Stanford CoreNLP from Java API: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: I was getting a null pointer exception during the build but wasn't able to trace it to a specific class. I'll try building it again and get back to you.Thank you!

Comment: This is the error I am continuing to get.
Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression.analyseCode(LambdaExpression.java:469) StanfordCoreNLPClient.java /CoreNLP/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline line 0 Java Problem

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing your build error, I am not familiar with Windows.  From now on we are going to try to periodically build the latest code and create a jar, so if you go to the GitHub site there is a download link for a jar that has the code as of today.  You can try using that jar instead of building the code in Eclipse.